# How to pass a R vector to shinyjs as a JS array?

Tags: r, shiny, shinyjs

I would like to pass a vector to `extendshinyjs` as a JS array, but it seems that the vector is actually passed as a string.
Here is my code:

**ui.R**

```
shinyUI( fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  extendShinyjs(text = jsCode),
 tags$div('color names',
  tags$p(class='colorName'),
  tags$p(class='colorName'),
  tags$p(class='colorName')
 )


))
```

**server.R**

```
shinyServer(
    function(input,output,session) {
      x <- c('red', 'yellow', 'green')
        js$pageCol(x)
      })
```

**global.R**

```
library(shinyjs)
library(shiny)
jscode <-  jsCode <- "shinyjs.pageCol = function(params){
                             var $spots = $('p').text(params);
      defaultParams = ['NA','NA','NA'];
      val = shinyjs.getParams(params, defaultParams);


$spots.each(function(i) {
$(this).text(val[i]);
}); 

}"
```

On the right what it looks like now, on the **left** what I would expect to see

[image: On the right how it looks like now, on the **left** what I would expect to see]

Answer (score 1):

The vector is not getting passed as a string, it is being converted to a javascript array. The javascript parameter is an array with one element, where that element is the vector that you passed in (just as I told you in the other thread - I wasn't lying!)

Try this:

```
shinyjs.pageCol = function(params){
  var cols = params[0];
  $('p').each(
    function(i, el) {
      $(el).text(cols[i]);
    }
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks, never meant to be skeptical, I simply know too little to move ahead from your previous answer :) btw, I am not sure what is being passed to `el` but simply adding `params[0]` to the code I posted worked